# How to get data from web service in window phone 8

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        StudentWS.StudentWSSoapClient MyClient = new StudentWS.StudentWSSoapClient();
        MyClient.GetStudentCompleted +=MyClient_GetStudentCompleted;
        MyClient.GetStudentAsync(CONNECTION_KEY);
    }

    void MyClient_GetStudentCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How to get the data from the method in webservice

Comment: Hard to believe this isn't covered in a tutorial somewhere

Comment: Hi, check in the EventArgs. Try something like "e.PropertyName".

Comment: tried but didn't find any useful properties : Cancelled,Equals,Error,GetHashCode,GetType,ToString,UserState